# How to turn off tensorflow contrib module warning

Tags: tensorflow, warnings

I'm still using tensorflow 1.15 and won't use tensorflow 2.0 for current project.

I'd like to know how can I turn off this warning message:

```
WARNING: The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.
```

I've read the metioned pages, but still don't know how to turn off that message.

Comment: import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

Comment: @Vedanshu TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL not working for tf.contrib warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a careful searching I found the answer in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27045#issuecomment-480691244

```
import tensorflow as tf
if type(tf.contrib) != type(tf): tf.contrib._warning = None
```